# For loop for bokeh in databricks

Tags: python, bokeh, databricks

Hi i would like to loop through for loop eg. few times code below to get few times the same graph in one databricks cell:

I imported library:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.embed import components, file_html
from bokeh.resources import CDN

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [6, 7, 2, 4, 5]


for i in range(5):
p = figure(title='test', x_axis_label = 'x values', y_axis_label='y values')
p.line(x,y, line_width =2)
html = file_html(p,CDN,'plot')
displayHTML(html)
```

I was trying to use for loop but still i am obtaining only one single graph in a cell.

Also tried with different modules, like here:

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [6, 7, 2, 4, 5]

for i in range(5):
  p = figure(title='test', x_axis_label = 'x values')
  p.line(x,y, line_width =2)
  output_file("line"+str(i)+".html")
  show(p)
```

But here i am not getting any result, nothing is plotted. Can you tell me why?

Tried this as well:

```
d={}
for i in range(5):
  p = figure(title='test', x_axis_label = 'x values')
  p.line(x,y, line_width =2)
  d["html{0}".format(i)]=file_html(p,CDN, 'plot' + str(i))

for j in d:
  displayHTML(j)
```

It looks like with bokeh in databricks it is possible to display only one graph per cell. Anyone knows if it is true?

Could you help me with the syntax for for loop to get it multiple times?

Comment: The code above does not have any for loop, so it is impossible to speculate. One plot is exactly what the code above would be expected to produce. You should present code that is actually similar or identical to the code that is causing problems.

Comment: @bigreddot updated. I also put what i tried already

Comment: You are in a notebook? What version? What version of Bokeh? Is there a specific reason you are not using `output_notebook` that is what is in all the docs, examples, and tutorials?

Comment: Yes I am trying to run it in azure databricks notebook, unfortunately i don't know how to check the version of the notebook. Bokeh library installed - 1.2.0. Yes - i don't have any results when i am trying to do it with output_file/output_notebook like it is in examples on bokeh site i am not getting any visualization - it looks like code is run without errors but i am not getting any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from other answers that there may be issues with Databricks using old notebook versions that Bokeh does not fully support. If the standard `output_notebook` is not working, but the `displayHTML` thing does, then I'd say your best bet is to collect the plots you want to show in a `column` layout, then show them all at once with a single call to `show` at the end:

```
from bokeh.layouts import column

plots = []
for i in range(5):
    p = figure(...)
    p.line(...)
    plots.append(p)

layout = column(*plots)

# only use this way for databricks
html = file_html(layout, CDN, 'plot')
displayHTML(html)
```

Comment: good solution, however still not working in databricks for me, but thanks for effort!

Comment: I updated with the `displayHTML` It is very unusual and answering with `show` is habitual. But if `displayHTML` works to show one plot it should  also work for a single layout.

Comment: Yup, you are right, thanks! I believe that instead of p in html you meant plots or layouts to print multiple graphs